# Atheros Bluetooth 4.0 Support API for Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, driver

I am involved in a Android Project that connects the sensor using Bluetooth 4.0. AFAIK android didn't support Bluetooth 4.0. I tried with my laptop bluetooth 4.0. I tried with Broadcom using [this](http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/). Later i came to know my Laptop Bluetooth 4.0 is Atheros Bluetooth 4.0 and later i searched for Atheros Bluetooth 4.0 API using android mobiles and tablets. I saw Qualcomm having Bluetooth 4.0 tablet. I want to know, is Atheros giving API for Bluetooth 4.0 for Android SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, long way of search, i found that up to today(23/12/12), Atheros not giving Bluetooth API for developers. But they are providing other API's for Audio, Camera, Device Info and Sensor(mobile shake). So, can't try on laptop also. Dgel comment and link helped me a lot and made me, come to the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Android Bluetooth (and other) API's are not specific to the hardware (or software stack).

They are generic and fairly high-level, and Yes they include Bluetooth 4.0.

The actually support for BT 4 depends on the device.  Recent Nexus devices support BT4 (both in hardware and in software) as long as they have the Android 4.2 update.

If you root your device you can get to the 'raw' vendor API's, but I don't know what that looks like for BT4, or wheteher any of that is published.  In most cases that is Broadcom based, not Atheros.

EDIT:
I just saw this:
http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/
I'm not familiar with this, but I suspect that it was just a stop gap measure before BT4 was added to the official Android API in 4.1.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. As far as I know, even Android 4.2 does not include support for Bluetooth 4.0. [This statement](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/cuckoo/cookootm-the-watch-for-the-connected-generation/posts/352332) from the Cookoo watch project summarizes the sorry state of Android Bluetooth support quite well.

Comment: @dgel Yikes, you are correct (about no BLE in the new Android 4.2 stack).  That is disappointing and rather odd.

Comment: @Tom: See my question, i already mentioned the link, that what you had given in your EDIT. Broadcom gave support before, but now devices updated to 4.1, so there is no support. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @dgel: Then is there any other way to achieve?

Comment: @Abdul: The only android device that can do BLE now is the Motorola RAZR because Motorola provides their own BLE libraries. The only option for all other devices (included the Nexus 4) is to wait until Google gets their act together and releases a new version of android with BLE in the Bluetooth stack- which thousands of developers around the world are hoping and praying will occur very soon.

Comment: @dgel: When i googled, Motorola RAZR and RAZR MAXX have updated the OS to 4.1, so there is no supported library for 4.1. They are writing it.